# does oracle database 10g express editon support the following

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

the designing.making/deploying/management of a distributed database?

or do i need to buy the versions for the above?

if it 10g express has this support, will there be a central point to which my web application will connect, or do i have to write connection strings to connect to each server making "the distributed database "

please also refer to this post 
[Oracle distributed databases and MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320708/oracle-distibuted-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Express Edition is limited to a single CPU and 4GB of data on a single server.  That's why it's free. If you want to use it in a distributed configuration you will have to write the glue yourself.